# How to get values between multiple delimitted feilds

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm looking to extract the hostname and IP address from the each line in a file data, hostname will be extracted from `cn=mykosts001` ie `mykosts001` and IP address `ipHostNumber=192.168.18.118` ie `192.168.18.118`.

Below is the file that contains the data..

```
$ cat hosts.tx
dn: cn=mykosts001+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.118,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,o=rocks.com

dn: cn=mykosts002+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.119,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,o=rocks.com

dn: cn=mykosts003+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.120,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,o=rocks.com

dn: cn=mykosts004+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.121,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,o=rocks.com
```

### EDIT:

```
dn: cn=mykosts005+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.122,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,
 o=rocks.com
```

for the above edited line, in this case as `o=rocks.com` comes to another line it also prints the `rocks.com` as it comes after `=`.

What I have tried:

```
$ cat hosts.tx | sed '/^$/d' | cut -d"=" -f2-3
mykosts001+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.118,ou
mykosts002+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.119,ou
mykosts003+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.120,ou
mykosts004+ipHostNumber=192.168.18.121,ou
```

I tried above but not getting an idea to get the hostname and IP only.

Desired Output:

```
mykosts001 192.168.18.118
mykosts002 192.168.18.119
mykosts003 192.168.18.120
mykosts004 192.168.18.121
```

Comment: Great question - clear, concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you'd tried so far and a statement of what it is you're trying to do. A breath of fresh air!

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for the motivational words, i love to see your solutions, good to see the solution provided, i'm testing the solution on a large data-set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[=+,]' '/^dn:/{print $2, $4}' file
mykosts001 192.168.18.118
mykosts002 192.168.18.119
mykosts003 192.168.18.120
mykosts004 192.168.18.121
```

Comment: Thanks for the short and nice solution +1.

Comment: This works great, however as testing on a dataset, i see i have few line where the line breaks after comma which i edited in the Post, can have a check if line starts with `dn` the check for these two values. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: One way around i found a work around like `awk '$1 ~ /^dn:/' hosts.txt | awk -F'[=+,]' 'NF{print $2, $4}'` but i know its not that efficient.

Comment: @kulfi it can be simplified to `awk -F'[=+,]' '$1=="dn"{print $2,$4}' hosts.txt`. The purpose of `NF` in the answer is filtering out blank lines, `$1=="dn"` will do that as well while checking if the first field is `dn`.

Comment: @EdMorton, many thanks , my stupidity could not get that simple approach.

Comment: @oguzismail, thnx a lot for explaining the fact and advising a trick.